# CSS Text Transform HTML Error, Jquery, SQL

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't know if this is a bug in Jquery, HTML, CSS or SQL error but I have to find out. I am using text-transform to make all user input to be in uppercase. But when I save this information to a database, all the letters are in lowercase.(I had typed them with CAPS LOCK off since they were being changed to uppercase anyway)

Here is what I am using in my html css `style="text-transform:uppercase;"`
I am using jquery 1.7 and saving to SQL 2008 R2 Standard. FYI, I am using AJAX post to save this information. Browser I am using is Firefox 10 and Chrome 17

Comment: text-transform only affects the display of the text, it doesn't alter the data

Comment: @steveax: That's an answer (and a correct one at that), not a comment.

Comment: @steveax How do I alter then?

Comment: @SKS It can't be my SQl code. It would be silly to say toLowerCase() when you want the data to uppercase

Answer (score 0):

use and javascript function for replace upper case.

```
<input type='text' class='upper-case' />
```

---

```
$(function(){
   $(".upper-case").keyup(function(){
         $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

using CSS `text-transform:uppercase` or `lowercase` is to display the data/information in proper case. therefore when any body seeing your website should not get annoying text.

Therefore CSS is the styling where you can format the case and for visual purpose only. Also it has nothing to do with your jQuery `text-transform`

now coming to your point that it does not store information in proper case (in your question uppercase). While you want to save the data in SQL 2008 R2 using jQuery you should use the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("div").text("For this type jQuery found.");
            $("div").text($("div").text().toUpperCase());
    });
</script>
```

`.toUpperCase()` function will change your text inside `div` to uppercase and you can save the data to SQL server with all your saving method.

Hope the above helps you to get a clear use of CSS `text-transform` and string `toUpperCase()` and also the difference between them.